# Cómo implemetar JSDoc en proyecto Spring

Tags: javascript, java, javadoc, jsdoc

Estoy intentando documentar un proyecto Spring, en al cual con JavaDoc funciona excelente para el código de Java, pero es proyecto tiene implementado también peticiones Ajax utilizando archivos de JS que también me gustaría documentar en el mismo proyecto.

Existe alguna dependencia para poder instalar JSDoc? estoy utilizando NetBeans, y documentar con JavaDoc es muy sencillo, basta con generar JavaDoc y ya está. La idea es documentar Java que ya está, archivos JavaScript y también el JSP, pero tratar de implementarlo en el mismo proyecto mediante dependencias, o qué herramienta existen o recomiendan para documentar Java, JavaScript y JSP

```js
/**
 * Represents a book.
 * @constructor
 * @param {string} title - The title of the book.
 * @param {string} author - The author of the book.
 */
function Book(title, author) {
}
```

Esa es la forma de documentar que es similar a la de JavaDoc. Espero sus comentarios!!!